# Left (right) eigenvalues of quaternion Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition, quaternions

I have problem with calculating left eigenvalues for quaternion Matrices. Let's take a look at article 'Geršgorin type theorems for quaternionic matrices
- Fuzhen Zhang':

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbPke.png)

The right eigenvalues are easy to calculate but im trying to work out how to calculate the left eigenvalues. I dont really know how to compute the det[$\chi_{(A-tI_{n})}]$ - I mean the matrix before calculating determinant

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkV8V.png)

So basically I want to see how calculate $Ax=\lambda x $ and my $\lambda$ will be the left eigenvalue of matrix A. I tried to use complex representation of quaternions for that but I get lost in calculations.

In next article 'On left eigenvalues of a quaternionic matrix Liping Huang a ,∗,1, Wasin Sob,2 ', we have definitions and theorem to calculate the left eigenvalues for 2x2 matrices:

[definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYbVR.png)

[theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qFl3.png)

And what I want to know, how to calculate in a raw form left and right eigenvalues and also by using that theorem for 2x2 matrix. I hope someone can explain it to me by calculating them step by step or maybe just some hints. After that maybe i will be able to check more examples if my calculations are correct, that would be awesome.

Comment: Obvious question: what does $\chi_A$ mean? I assume it means turning quaternionic matrices (including column vectors) into double-sized complex matrices. If so, you need to decide if you're treating $\Bbb H^n$ as a left or right complex vector space.

Comment: I have a problem with calculating  left eigenvalues of quaternion matrix without using complex representation.

Comment: You neither confirmed nor denied my suspicion that $\chi_A$ represents turning quaternionic matrices into complex matrices. If my suspicion is right, then why bother linking that image when you're specifically trying to do it a different way (and what other way are you considering)? If my suspicion is wrong, then what does $\chi_A$ represent?

Comment: $\chi_{A}$ your assumption was right. But my problem is, first we create  B=A-tIn matrix then we transform it into 2n x 2n complex matrix using $B=B_{2}+B_{2}j$ I guess

Comment: I want to calculate eigenvalues like in real case by solving the equation Ax=tx, Ax=tx and left eigenvalues using 'click' image for left eigenvalues.